# GitHub - Pull localy an existing project and replace existing files without removing non existing one

Tags: git, github, repository

For some reasons I'm working on a same project in two different computers.

I would like to work in one of them, save the changes to a commit and push it to a GitHub repository. When I get home, if I want to keep on working on the project I just want to pull it from GitHub and work from where I left it.

The problem is that there are files in my project which I don't want to upload to GitHub (as API credentials, test files and more) and I have them declared on my `.gitignore` file.

I want to ask you guys if, imagine I have an older version of the project in my computer with all the credentials and test files on it; I `cd` to it and do the pull: will it just replace the existing files with the new version of them keeping the files that are not contained in the GitHub commit but they are in my local repository, or will it just smash the whole local repository and smash credentials and test files?

Is there a better way to achieve what I want without having to copy manually non-existing files?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but you can stimulate the situation with three local repositories. One works as the Github repository *foo* and the others as the two local repositories *bar1* and *bar2*. Reproduce their revisions and files in *bar1* and *bar2*, and in them you can create a remote *origin_foo* with `git remote add origin_foo <path_to_foo>`. Then run commands like `git push origin_foo master` and `git pull origin_foo master` to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pull from the home computer, it can do **one of the following** things -

1. Successfully pull changes from remote to local if git finds out there are no conflicting changes.
2. Give an error if changes from remote can not be taken directly since
   there are conflicting changes in your local branch.

In the later case, you will have to resolve the conflicts and then the changes from remote can be successfully merged to your local branch.

If you have some uncommitted files in your repo like API creds, tests, etc that you mentioned and if you do a git pull, git will give you an error and tell you to commit or stash your changes.

The best bet here to preserve your local files and still pull changes from remote is - Stash!

If you run

```
git stash
```

it will move your uncommitted files to an area called as Stash. Once you do this, your local repo will be cleaned and you will be able to pull changes from remote. If you now want your changes back, you can do

```
git stash pop
```

This will pop recently stashed changes back in your repo! You can stash as many times as you want and git maintains it in the list. It can be accessed by

```
git stash list
```

and you can even selectively take items out from stash list via -

```
git stash apply stashListNumber
```

*Note: You will be able to stash only those files which are being tracked by git. If you add some files and do not commit at all, you can keep them in your repo without having to worry about any conflicts and can still pull from remote successfully.*

I hope this helps.